# How to download intraday data regarding a particular stock exchange from bloomberg at one time

Tags: bloomberg

Good day
I would like to know how to download the intraday data regarding a particular stick exchange at one time, (I need to analyse all the equities listed on it)

Second I need to verify that my understanding is correct regarding to what is displayed on the screening so (bear with me please)[image]

1). the size 7838 *10,48k means that the we have 7838 shares available for bid and 10,48k are available for ask (the depth of that bid ask spread) right??

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Hit the help key, bloomberg has a help service for subscribers.

Someone will walk you through it free of additional charge (you (your firm) are paying for it in the monthly subscription fee).